# Javascript Date Formatting mm/dd/yyyy from date object

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to convert the variable below to a date in the format of MM/DD/YYYY when i try to build the string I get a type error. I want the final variable to output 01/21/2022. How can I resolve this. I tried to change the variable from string to date. Is it that I need to use toString()?

```
UpdatedDate = Fri Jan 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST);

var year = UpdatedDate.getFullYear();
var month = UpdatedDate.getMonth() + 1;
var day = UpdatedDate.getDate();
UpdatedDate = month + '/' + day + '/'+ year;


Type Error: Cannot find function getFullYear in object Fri Jan 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST). (threadScript#1)
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: also show how you instantiate `UpdatedDate`

Comment: `UpdatedDate` as no var, no quote if it is  a string, and no more clarity in your question...

Comment: that i sthe only date the system accepts its old i know

Answer (score 1):

> use date constructor
> more info about Date constructor : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

```js
const UpdatedDate = "Fri Jan 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)";
const date = new Date(UpdatedDate);
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getDate();

console.log(`${month}-${day}-${year}`)
```